# Prometheus : Exporting custom php metrics not showing up in prometheus

Tags: php, prometheus

I am working on Prometheus, where I would like to export PHP fpm related metrics to Prometheus. For that I am using

https://github.com/Lusitaniae/phpfpm_exporter
, which serves on port-9253. I can confirm that the service is running properly from the pod I want to share metrics to.

here is my prometheus.yml:

```
- job_name: 'phpfpm'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      action: replace
      regex: ([^:]+):.*
      replacement: $1:9253
      target_label: __address__
```

Pod logs:

```
ps -ef | grep php
root        46     1  0 04:36 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root        48    46  0 04:36 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
root        49    46  0 04:36 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
root        86     1  0 04:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/phpfpm_exporter --phpfpm.socket-paths /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
root        93    62  0 04:36 ?        00:00:00 php /var/www/html/artisan --timeout=180 queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
root       148   127  0 04:48 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto php
root@auth-service-deployment-756c48d967-vpsnr:/var/www/html# less /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock is not a regular file (use -f to see it)
root@auth-service-deployment-756c48d967-vpsnr:/var/www/html# phpfpm_exporter --phpfpm.socket-paths /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
2021/03/02 04:48:31 Starting phpfpm_exporter (version=0.5.0, branch=HEAD, revision=9cb855b0e40f98db3bfae60d34d7b87834329310)
2021/03/02 04:48:31 Build context (go=go1.12.6, user=root@a53eecf46f97, date=20190621-12:09:02)
2021/03/02 04:48:31 Starting Server: :9253
```

But when I search in Prometheus for phpfpm or php_fpm, nothing shows up. What am I missing?

Comment: what does prometheus say about this configuration in Status-> Targets? It sounds like the target isn't scraped.